# How to detect the frequence of a sound in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

How can I detect if a sound is playing in the hearing range?

For example,

Show a silence icon if:

- The range is lower than *20 Hz*,
- The range is higher than *20 kHz*.

instead `stream.paused` is `false`.

Comment: You mean in an `<audio>` element?

Comment: @Oriol Yes, or with Javascript. The answer is if there is a way to do that.

Comment: The highest frequency that a standard audio file (44.1 kHz) can contain is approximately 20 kHz, but if you still want to get the frequency data, use  [AnalyserNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode)

Comment: In my third decade, I can only hear ~16kHz, and this seems pretty much on par: not sure what the 'high end' of my hearing was when I was a kid, but 20kHz is generally given as an *upper bound* for human hearing (wikipedia says 28kHz under 'ideal laboratory conditions'), and not necessarily a relevant number for a particular demographic. Lower-grade audio equipment may also clip the ideal, even if it were encoded in a higher-quality source; and audio encodings (eg. MP3) are notorious for lossy clipping. That aside, the question of "how to determine the frequency of an audio source"..

Comment: Encoding limits: audio CD ~ 22.05kHz, DVD/HDTV ~ 24kHz, from a 'raw' source, nevermind what happens between there and someone's ear/brain. (Or any clippings/loss before it was originally encoded.)

Comment: @nanilab I wouldn't waste time with that.  Anything outside of hearing range probably won't actually be in your sample anyway.  Even if you did have something above 20 kHz, it won't be encoded properly due to sample rate limitations.  If you're really determined, the best thing to do is to use a BiquadFilterNode in a bandpass mode with a very wide Q.  Then use the AnalyserNode to determine how much signal you're left with.  If it's below a particular threshold you like, consider it silent.  Again though... I really wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: @Brad Thanks Brad. My idea was to create a script that display a sound as muted even if it is playing, only if is out of the range.

Comment: @nanilab Why not just leave out the frequency range part?  If something was rockin' my subwoofer at 10Hz, even if you can't hear it without distortion, I'd want to know where it was playing.  Just detect levels, and show as muted if it's below a threshold.

Comment: @Brad Good idea :) thanks buddy. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [pitch detection](https://github.com/rserota/wad#pitch-detection) audio library.

Example:

```
var voice = new Wad({source : 'mic' });
var tuner = new Wad.Poly();
tuner.add(voice);
voice.play();

tuner.updatePitch() // The tuner is now calculating the pitch and note name of its input 60 times per second. These values are stored in tuner.pitch and tuner.noteName.

var logPitch = function(){
    console.log(tuner.pitch, tuner.noteName)
    requestAnimationFrame(logPitch)
};
logPitch();
// If you sing into your microphone, your pitch will be logged to the console in real time.

tuner.stopUpdatingPitch(); // Stop calculating the pitch if you don't need to know it anymore.
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you can find the hz with javascript.  You'll probably have to use the web audio API.  However, with javascript you can definitely check and set volume on a numeric scale.  Check out the details and sample code here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Example values:
1.0 is highest volume (100%. This is default)
0.5 is half volume (50%)
0.0 is silent (same as mute)

Comment: 1.0 isn't technically highest... it's just as high as you can go before clipping when sending the audio back to your sound card or when converting to any standard integer PCM handling.